# Is there way to modify Number class

Tags: actionscript-3

At clasic windows calculator, nubers are separated by comma, like: 4,5
I wish to have it same in flash, but:

Number("4,5") //output: NaN

Is there any way modify Number class to get this result?

Number("4,5") //output: 4.5
Number("4.5") //output: 4.5

Also string with spaces can be considered as number...

trace(Number("10000" )) //output: 10000
trace(Number("10 000")) //output: NaN

one more example about numbers which can be fixed:

trace(4.3 - 1.1) //output 3.1999999999999997
trace(Number(4.3 - 1.1).toFixed(1)) //output: 3.2

Comment: If the number is always provided as a string, why not just replace all `,` with `.` in that string?

Comment: yes yes, now I have two functions for convert String to number and vice versa, but I think better way is modify Number class.

Comment: @Orien You can't modify or extend Number class since it is final. I suggest writing some utility/helper factory class for producing numbers from string input and implement there logic for any case you need. Or you can write your own Number class and define a method like "toNumber"

Comment: thanks guys for you quic response. Now im working on some as3 help tools like mcString [link](https://github.com/MerlinEl/ORIENTOOLS/blob/master/orien/tools/mcString.as) maybe I will try to write new Number class.

Comment: @Orien modifying a built in class is never a good idea.

Comment: @null maybe you right. Yesterday I spend 2hours to find an bug in script. And it was little strange to understand this: [code](trace(4.3 - 1.1) //output: 3.1999999999999997)

Comment: @Orien that's simply how computers work. IEEE 754 has limited precision and cannot contain every number (basically speaking). There are dozens of questions about this on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Number , use a function and send the values to it , just like this

```
function convertNumber(var:String):Number
{
 var arr:Array;

 arr = var.split(",");
 if(arr.length >0)
    {
    var sendStr:String =  arr[0] + "." + arr[1];
    return Number(sendStr);
    }

 arr = var.split(" ");
 if(arr.length >0)
    {
    var sendStr:String =  arr[0] + arr[1];
    return Number(sendStr);
    }

    return Number(var)

}
```

use convertNumber(4,5) to get output as 4.5